# Problem Slide-In/Out JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width, slidetoggle

Slide out is no problem i only have problem about slide in that doesnt show up and i think it didnt catch their first IF width equal 0px. sorry im really noobs about jQuery.

CODE:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ShowHideComment").click(function(){
        if ($(".iframe_comment").width() == "0px"){
            $(".iframe_comment").animate({width: "800px"}, {queue:false, duration:1000});
        }
        else{
            $(".iframe_comment").animate({width: "0px"}, {queue:false, duration:1000
           });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties):

> All animated properties should be animated to a *single numeric value*

You're not dealing with CSS property values here, but with plain integers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ShowHideComment").click(function(){
        var $comment = $(".iframe_comment");
        if ($comment.width() == 0){
            $comment.animate({width: 800}, {queue:false, duration:1000});
        }
        else{
            $comment.animate({width: 0}, {queue:false, duration:1000});
        }
    });
});
```

Also [see `width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

> The difference between `.css(width)`
>   and `.width()` is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value

Comment: wow cool thanks Tomalak... how can i add function when complete animation? i tried add function() { in after duration:1000. it doesnt work..

Comment: There is a `complete` argument for `animate()`. Put your callback function there. Also, it's unlikely that you really need `queue:false`. Your animation will always begin immediately as long as there is no other animation already going on.

Comment: here i tried: `$comment.animate({width: 0}, {queue:false, duration:450, function() { $comment.hide() } });` then doesnt work =/

Comment: @user: `$comment.animate({width: 0}, {queue:false, duration:450, complete:function() { $comment.hide() } });`

Answer (score 0):

`.width()` returns numeric value. 
This line `if ($(".iframe_comment").width() == "0px")`
should be
`if ($(".iframe_comment").width() == 0)`